# Bash get substring to variable using regex

Tags: regex, bash

Using bash script I need to search string like `version = '1.8.1-SNAPSHOT'` from text file and get value `'1.8.1-SNAPSHOT'` into variable.

I tryed to use the next code, but no result:

```
version=$(grep -P "version\s?=\s?'([a-zA-Z.\d-]){5,20}?'" file.txt) 
regex="'([a-zA-Z.\d-]){5,30}?'"
value=`expr match "$version" '([a-zA-Z.\d-]){5,30}?'`
```

What is wrong and are there another way?

Some of text file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE')
    }
}

springBootVersion = '2.0.7.RELEASE'


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

// for Glassfish
//apply plugin: 'war'

jar {
    baseName = 'work-space'
    version = '1.8.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Desired string need to be `'1.8.1-SNAPSHOT'` into variable for the next manipulation.

Comment: Try `version="$(grep -oP "version\s*=\s*'\K[^']+" file)"`. See https://ideone.com/LtxK2g

Comment: Thanks, but i also need to get from version = '1.8.1-SNAPSHOT' the finish result like '1.8.1-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: Show file.txt and desired string.

Comment: https://ideone.com/LtxK2g shows the `1.8.1-SNAPSHOT` - isn't it expected?

Comment: Yes! Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
version="$(grep -oP "version\s*=\s*'\K[^']+" file)"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/LtxK2g).

As you are using `P` option, I assume you may use PCRE regex with your `grep`. To output the match, you also need to add `o` option.

The regex you need is `version\s*=\s*'\K[^']+`:

- `version` - matches `version` substring
- `\s*=\s*` - `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `'` - a `'` char
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[^']+` - 1 or more chars other than `'`